# Run windows batch script on file change

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

As part of the corporate policy I'm forced to look at ugly, branded wallpaper and manual change is turned off, as being managed by the company. I have come up with a following script, that when run, changes the wallpaper. It is based on swapping the file that is used by the company theme.

```
set tapeta="C:\my_wallpaper\Branding.JPG"

copy /Y %tapeta% C:\bin\Branding\Wallpaper

rem taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
rem start explorer.exe

RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
```

The commented out part works every time, but has a side effect of closing all open folders. The next line works sometimes.

The real problem is, the managed system replaces the file back every now and then - sometimes few times a day. This means I have to run this script manually few times a day. Is there a way to run the script on file change? Or is there any other way to solve this?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe it's enough to set the "read only" attribute to your file. Maybe not, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Perhaps, your company should reconsider your position. If the amount of time you have spare is sufficient for you to be often viewing their branded wallpaper, you are clearly either not working hard enough, or much too efficient for your role.

Comment: Why aren't you using Group Policies to lock this down?

Comment: @Compo LOL - your comment actually prompted me to minimize all applications to take a look at my wallpaper (which is probably the same for years).

Comment: Stephan - this was the first thing I did and it doesn't work.
Compo - I hope it's the second option :D although it is such an eye sore that even a glance once in a while is enough - and I deal with it outside my working hours ;)